# How to protect mysql table from accidental mass update

Tags: mysql

Occasional updates statements without "where" clause may easily destroy all your data, I'm always getting nervous when typing UPDATE statement in mysql console, being afraid to press enter before typing "where".
So, I'm wondering if it is possible to protect table from update queries w/o "where" clause on mySQL level? Kind of simply disable it.
 And yes, I'm well aware of backups :-) Thanks!

Comment: I usually add some garbage text before starting a major query when I need to make sure it doesn't get executed by accident..

Comment: You could use --safe-updates or a client which supports this kind of protection - such as MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an insult: turn on [--i-am-a-dummy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-tips.html#safe-updates) mode.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has the the --safe-updates switch, most other databases don't. This is why in cases like that I personally always start writing with the where clause:

```
where x > 134;
```

and then move the cursor to the beginning and add:

```
update whatever set a = 2 where x > 134;
```

this way the query has a syntax error until the very moment it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a trigger in tables that you want to prevent it.